# How to insert multi data form to database

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to insert some files and json data to database with django. (I'm totally new to Django, thus, please have mercy :) )

My model is as follows :

```
class Files(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   file_type = models.ForeignKey(to=FileType)
   file = models.FileField(upload_to='media/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.file_type.name
```

The view where I fetch the data is as follows :

```
def save_user(request):
    user = json.loads(request.POST.get("user"))
    for file_key in request.FILES.keys():
        file = Files()
        file.file_type = FileType.get_by_key(file_key.split('/')[1])
        file.file = request.FILES[file_key]
        file.save()

    return HttpResponse("User saving...")
```

And the data that I get in request is as follows :

**request.FILES**

```
<MultiValueDict: {'file/ID_CARD': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: check.png (image/png)>], 'file/STATUTES': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: pictures.xlsx (application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet)>]}>
```

and **user**

```
{'companyName': 'Autralis', 'btwNumber': '84515', 'address': 'Hundelgemsesteenweg 575', 'country': 'Belgium', 'zipcode': '9820', 'place': 'Merelbeke', 'phone': '+32 486386069', 'mobilePhone': '+32 486386069', 'firstName': 'Maida', 'lastName': 'Mesanovic', 'email': 'maida@autralis.com', 'userName': 'Maida', 'password': '123', 'confirmPassword': '123', 'files': [{'file_type': 'LETTER_HEAD', 'values': {'active': False, 'fileName': 'Blank letterhead', 'file': None}}, {'file_type': 'COMPANY_PICTURE', 'values': {'active': False, 'fileName': 'Company photo', 'file': None}}, {'file_type': 'ID_CARD', 'values': {'active': True, 'fileName': 'check', 'file': {}}}, {'file_type': 'STATUTES', 'values': {'active': True, 'fileName': 'pictures', 'file': {}}}], 'terms': True, 'emailNotifications': True, 'smsNotifications': True}
```

How can I add it to the database?

Comment: what is multi data?

Comment: @e4c5 I mean json data, images and files.